# How To Sort A Map By Datetime?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, list, map

I have a `List` of records containing date and time (e.g. `2017-01-23T11:06:33.000+0000`). I want to sort it by these `Datetime` values.

```
public Map<String,MBT_SFFB__Conversation__c> objmappost {get;set;}
objpostlist=[
    SELECT ... FROM MBT_SFFB__Conversation__c WHERE...
    ORDER BY MBT_SFFB__Published_Date__c DESC
];
if(objpostlist.size()>0)
{
   for(MBT_SFFB__Conversation__c  objpost: objpostlist)
   {                         
        objmappost.put(objpost.Id,objpost); // inserts post into the map                        
   }
}
```

Querying in DB returns perfect result in query editor.

I want to sort this map according to the `MBT_SFFB__Published_Date__c` descending.

Answer (score 2):

`Maps` are by definition unsorted collections. If you want to maintain sort order, keep a separate `List` property for that.

```
List<Id> orderedKeys = new List<Id>();
for (MyObject__c record : records)
{
    orderedKeys.add(record.Id);
    myMap.put(record.Id, record);
}
```

Note that you don't need to check if the list is empty, as in that case your `for` loop doesn't consume any resources. You can also make it even more efficient on heap usage by implementing [SOQL For Loops](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_SOQL.htm):

> SOQL for loops iterate over all of the sObject records returned by a SOQL query. The syntax of a SOQL for loop is either:
>
> ```
> for (***variable*** : [soql_query]) {
>     code_block
> }
> ```
>
> ...
>
> #### SOQL For Loops Versus Standard SOQL Queries
>
> SOQL for loops differ from standard SOQL statements because of the method they use to retrieve sObjects. While the standard queries discussed in [SOQL and SOSL Queries](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL.htm) can retrieve either the count of a query or a number of object records, SOQL for loops retrieve all sObjects, using efficient chunking with calls to the query and queryMore methods of the SOAP API. Developers should always use a SOQL for loop to process query results that return many records, to avoid the limit on [heap size](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm#total_heap_size_limit_desc).